# Regular expression to exclude a string pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, database, dataframe

Please, I want to rename the columns of my table by removing the year label. Here are my columns names :

```
"PROV_201601" "MNT_201602" "PROV_201612" .... and so on !
```

My objective is to remove the "2016" from the name of the column. I am only familiar with R but not with regular expressions.

Any help is appreciated !

Thank you.

Comment: Why not simply `gsub(""2016,"","PROV_201601" "MNT_201602" "PROV_201612")`

Comment: Yes you are right ! Thank you @amrrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `sub` to match a `_` capture as a group followed by four digits (`\\d{4}`) and replace with the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`) or use `_`

```
sub("(_)\\d{4}", "\\1", v1)
#[1] "PROV_01" "MNT_02"  "PROV_12"
```

If it is specific to 2016 then

```
sub("2016", "", v1)
#[1] "PROV_01" "MNT_02"  "PROV_12"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("PROV_201601", "MNT_201602", "PROV_201612")
```

Comment: Super ! Many thanks. If you can recommend any regex tutos, feel free to tell us. Thank you @akrun

Comment: @CHAMISoufiane  Glad to know that it works.  You can check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2):

First, use `sub()` to replace all instances of `"2016"` with `""`. This will eliminate 2016 from the character strings.

```
col1 <- c("PROV_201601", "MNT_201602", "PROV_201612")
col2 <- sub("2016", "", col1)
```

Now rename your columns of data frame `dat` using `names()`:

```
names(dat) <- col2
```

Comment: @CHAMISoufiane `sub("2016", "", col1, fixed=TRUE)` will be even faster.